Como logro que las imágenes no me ocupen demasiado espacio en memoria en JavaFX?
Estoy creando un catálogo para escritorio.
Esta clase es el controlador de una ventana fxml en javaFX. Está compuesta por un anchorpane de fondo y dentro de este hay otro anchorpane mas pequeño que contiene el scrollPane.
El controlador se encargará de crear un gridpane para distribuir las fotos e hiperlinks, 4 columnas y las filas se incrementan a medida que se generan los componentes.
Mi problema radica en que en el método cargar llega un Arraylist con 5000 o más Audiovisuales. Al comenzar a generarse los imageView y los hyperlinks el consumo de memoria ram crece a razón de 500mb cada 1000 Audiovisuales por lo tanto el consumo de memoria asciende a los 2.5GB (horrible).
He intentado cargar las fotos he imageView a medida que se desplaza el scrollPane pero no he logrado una implementación adecuada de liberación de memoria. En el método scrollMoviendose(ScrollEvent event) al final del código puse comentarios de lo que quiero lograr con respecto a la liberación de memoria. Sería cargar inicialmente unos 20 audiovisuales en el gridpane y luego al scrollear conseguir la funcionalidad.
No puedo disminuir el tamaño de las fotos por petición del cliente. Todas las fotos cargadas son diferentes. La clase Audiovisual tiene 2 atributos String uno con el nombre y otro con la dirección de la foto ambos con sus respectivos get y set. Soy nuevo usando javaFX y esta es mi segunda publicación en stackOverflow, estoy totalmente abierto a sugerencias y críticas de mejora y optimización del código. Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.
public class CatalogoInternoVistaController implements Initializable {

    //Atributos de la ventana
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink linkA;  
    @FXML
    private TextField txtBuscar;
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scpCrollPane;
    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitPane;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink linkTodos;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink linkOtros;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink linkNumeros;

    //Atributos del controlador
    private final ArrayList<Hyperlink> hyperlinks = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Audiovisual> audiovisuales;
    private final GridPane principal = new GridPane();

    //Método inicial de las ventanas
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // Deshabilitar el arrastre del divisor
        splitPane.getDividers().forEach(divider -> {
            divider.positionProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.1027);
            });
        });
    }

    //Sets y Gets
    public void setAudiovisuales(List<Audiovisual> audiovisuales) {
        this.audiovisuales = audiovisuales;
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    @FXML
    private void Atras() {
        f.retroceder();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    @FXML
    private void Alante() {
        f.avanzar();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    @FXML
    private void Todos() {
        linkTodos.setVisited(false);
        mostrarInicialTodos();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    //Comienzan las acciones de los hyperlinks
    @FXML
    private void Otros() {
        linkOtros.setVisited(false);
        mostrarInicialOtros();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    @FXML
    private void Numeros() {
        linkNumeros.setVisited(false);
        mostrarInicialNumero();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    @FXML
    private void A() {
        mostrarInicialLetra(linkA.getText(), linkA);
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */  

    //Comienzan las acciones del TextField de búsqueda
    @FXML
    private void buscar() {

        // Obtener el texto ingresado en el campo de búsqueda
        String filtroNombre = txtBuscar.getText();
        int index = -1; // Variable para almacenar el índice de la primera coincidencia

        // Comprobar si el campo de búsqueda está vacío
        if (filtroNombre.isEmpty()) {
            // Restaurar el texto original de los hyperlinks si el filtro está vacío
            for (int i = 0; i < hyperlinks.size(); i++) {
                hyperlinks.get(i).setPrefWidth(200); // Establecer un ancho preferido fijo
                hyperlinks.get(i).setText(hyperlinks.get(i).getText()); // Reiniciar el texto a su valor original
                hyperlinks.get(i).setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY); // Mostrar solo el texto
            }
        } else {
            // Si hay un filtro, cambiar el color del texto según las coincidencias
            for (Hyperlink h : hyperlinks) {
                String nombre = h.getText(); // Obtener el texto del Hyperlink actual
                String filtro = filtroNombre.toLowerCase(); // Convertir el filtro a minúsculas para comparación
                TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(); // Crear un nuevo TextFlow para contener el texto
                flow.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

                // Iterar sobre cada carácter del nombre
                for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length(); i++) {
                    Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(nombre.charAt(i))); // Crear un objeto Text para cada carácter

                    // Verificar si el carácter es parte de una coincidencia con el filtro
                    if (nombre.toLowerCase().substring(i).startsWith(filtro)) {
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = hyperlinks.indexOf(h); // Guardar el índice de la primera coincidencia
                        }

                        // Añadir el texto coincidente en rojo, en negrita y subrayado
                        for (int j = 0; j < filtro.length() && j < nombre.length(); j++) {
                            Text redText = new Text(String.valueOf(nombre.charAt(i + j)));
                            redText.setFill(Color.RED); // Cambiar el color a rojo
                            redText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-underline: true"); // Aplicar estilo
                            flow.getChildren().add(redText); // Añadir el texto rojo al TextFlow
                        }
                        i += filtro.length() - 1; // Saltar los caracteres ya procesados
                    } else {
                        text.setFill(Color.WHITE); // Si no coincide, mantenerlo en negro
                        flow.getChildren().add(text); // Añadir el texto negro al TextFlow
                    }
                }

                // Establecer el gráfico del Hyperlink directamente con el TextFlow creado
                double longitud = calcularLongitud(flow); // Calcular la longitud del TextFlow
                if (longitud > 200) {
                    h.setPrefWidth(200); // Limitar el ancho preferido a 200 si es necesario
                } else {
                    h.setPrefWidth(longitud); // Ajustar el ancho preferido al tamaño del TextFlow
                }
                h.setGraphic(flow); // Establecer el gráfico del Hyperlink como el TextFlow
                h.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); // Mostrar solo el gráfico
                h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // Centrar el contenido en el Hyperlink
            }

            // Asegurarse de que la primera coincidencia sea visible en la interfaz
            if (index != -1) {
                ensureVisible(hyperlinks.get(index)); // Llamar a un método para hacer visible la coincidencia encontrada
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    //Comienza la lógica
    private double calcularLongitud(TextFlow t) {
        // Se establece la variable 'longitud' a 0. Esta variable se usará para calcular la longitud total del contenido del TextFlow.
        double longitud = 0;

        // Se itera sobre cada nodo hijo del TextFlow 't'.
        for (Node n : t.getChildren()) {
            // Se verifica si el nodo actual es una instancia de la clase 'Text'.
            if (n instanceof Text texto) {

                // Se establece la alineación del texto al centro.
                texto.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

                // Se establece el ancho de ajuste de texto (wrappingWidth) del objeto Text a la longitud actual. Esto determina dónde se ajustará el texto (se dividirá en varias líneas) si es necesario.
                texto.setWrappingWidth(longitud);

                // Se obtiene el ancho del objeto Text (después de que se haya ajustado el texto) usando 'getLayoutBounds().getWidth()'.
                // Se suma 6 a este ancho para agregar un pequeño espacio adicional (para padding o separación).
                // Se actualiza la longitud total sumando el ancho del texto (más el espacio adicional) a la longitud actual.
                longitud += texto.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 10;
            }
        }

        // Se devuelve la longitud total calculada.
        return longitud;
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    private void ensureVisible(Node node) {
        // Se obtiene el ancho y alto del contenido del ScrollPane. 
        // Esto nos da las dimensiones del área visible dentro del ScrollPane.
        double width = scpCrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double height = scpCrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        // Se obtienen las coordenadas del borde derecho e inferior del nodo 'node' en relación a su padre.
        // 'getMaxX()' y 'getMaxY()' dan la coordenada x del borde derecho y la coordenada y del borde inferior del nodo, respectivamente.
        double x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX();
        double y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();

        // Calcular la posición vertical y horizontal
        scpCrollPane.setVvalue(y / height);
        scpCrollPane.setHvalue(x / width);

        // Comprobar si el índice es válido y si está entre las últimas cuatro posiciones
        if (isHyperlinkInLastRow(principal, (Hyperlink) node)) {
            // Desplazar verticalmente al final
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                scpCrollPane.setVvalue(1.0);
            });
        }
        // Se llama a 'scpCrollPane.layout()' para forzar un rediseño del ScrollPane. 
        // Esto asegura que el ScrollPane se vuelva a dibujar correctamente después de que se haya modificado su posición.
        scpCrollPane.layout();
    }

    public boolean isHyperlinkInLastRow(GridPane gridPane, Hyperlink hyperlink) {
        // Obtener el índice de columna y fila del Hyperlink
        int rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(hyperlink) != null ? GridPane.getRowIndex(hyperlink) : 0;

        // Obtener el número total de filas en el GridPane
        int totalRows = gridPane.getChildren().stream()
                .filter(node -> GridPane.getRowIndex(node) != null)
                .mapToInt(node -> GridPane.getRowIndex(node))
                .max()
                .orElse(-1) + 1; // +1 porque el índice es cero 

        // Verificar si el Hyperlink está en la última fila
        return rowIndex == (totalRows - 1);
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     * @param recibido
     */
    public void cargar(List<Audiovisual> recibido) {
        principal.setPrefWidth(scpCrollPane.getPrefWidth() - 17);
        principal.setMinHeight(396);
        principal.setHgap(12);
        principal.setVgap(10);
        principal.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
        principal.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('imagenes/AZUL.jpg');"
                + "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                + "-fx-background-position: center center;"
                + "-fx-background-size: 100% 100%;");

        setAudiovisuales(recibido);
        mostrarInicialTodos();

        scpCrollPane.setContent(principal);
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    //Muestra todos los audiovisuales 
    public void mostrarInicialTodos() {
        txtBuscar.clear(); // Limpiar el campo de búsqueda
        principal.getChildren().clear(); // Limpiar el GridPane

        // Crear un Task para cargar las imágenes en segundo plano
        Task<Void> loadImagesTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < audiovisuales.size(); i += 10) {
                    // Cargar hasta 20 elementos
                    for (int j = i; j < Math.min(i + 10, audiovisuales.size()); j++) {
                        final int index = j;  // Necesario para el uso dentro de la expresión lambda
                        // Actualizar la UI solo en el hilo de JavaFX
                        javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(audiovisuales.get(index).getNombre());
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                            configurarImagen(hyperlink, imageView, index, audiovisuales.get(index).getFoto());
                        });
                    }

                    // Simular un proceso de carga; 
                    Thread.sleep(100); // Pausar para simular la carga (opcional)
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        // Iniciar el hilo de carga en segundo plano
        new Thread(loadImagesTask).start();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     * @param string
     * @param h
     */
    //Muestra todos los audiovisuales que empiecen con la letra que se corresponda al Hyperlink
    public void mostrarInicialLetra(String string, Hyperlink h) {
        h.setVisited(false);
        txtBuscar.clear();
        principal.getChildren().clear();

        char primerCharLink = string.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        // Crea un hilo secundario para cargar los audiovisuales
        new Thread(() -> {
            int count = -1;
            // Carga los audiovisuales de 10 en 10
            for (int i = 0; i < audiovisuales.size(); i += 10) {
                // Carga un grupo de 10 audiovisuales
                for (int j = i; j < Math.min(i + 10, audiovisuales.size()); j++) {
                    final int pasarJ = j;
                    char primerCharAudiovisual = audiovisuales.get(j).getNombre().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                    if (primerCharAudiovisual == primerCharLink) {
                        count++;
                        final int pasarCount = count;
                        Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(audiovisuales.get(j).getNombre());
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                        // Ejecuta configurarImagen en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (FX Application Thread)
                        Platform.runLater(() -> configurarImagen(hyperlink, imageView, pasarCount, audiovisuales.get(pasarJ).getFoto()));
                    }
                }

                // Espera un breve tiempo para evitar bloquear la interfaz de usuario
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Maneja la interrupción del hilo
                }
            }

            // Actualiza el contenido del ScrollPane en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
            Platform.runLater(() -> scpCrollPane.setContent(principal));
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    //Muestra todos los audiovisuales que empiecen con número 
    public void mostrarInicialNumero() {
        txtBuscar.clear();
        principal.getChildren().clear();

        new Thread(() -> {
            int count = -1;
            // Carga los audiovisuales de 10 en 10
            for (int i = 0; i < audiovisuales.size(); i += 10) {
                // Carga un grupo de 10 audiovisuales
                for (int j = i; j < Math.min(i + 10, audiovisuales.size()); j++) {
                    final int pasarJ = j;
                    char primerCharAudiovisual = audiovisuales.get(i).getNombre().charAt(0);
                    if (Character.isDigit(primerCharAudiovisual)) {
                        count++;
                        final int pasarCount = count;
                        Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(audiovisuales.get(j).getNombre());
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                        // Ejecuta configurarImagen en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (FX Application Thread)
                        Platform.runLater(() -> configurarImagen(hyperlink, imageView, pasarCount, audiovisuales.get(pasarJ).getFoto()));
                    }
                }

                // Espera un breve tiempo para evitar bloquear la interfaz de usuario
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Maneja la interrupción del hilo
                }
            }

            // Actualiza el contenido del ScrollPane en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
            Platform.runLater(() -> scpCrollPane.setContent(principal));
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    //Muestra todos los audiovisuales que no empiecen con número o letra
    public void mostrarInicialOtros() {
        txtBuscar.clear();
        principal.getChildren().clear();

        new Thread(() -> {
            int count = -1;
            // Carga los audiovisuales de 10 en 10
            for (int i = 0; i < audiovisuales.size(); i += 10) {
                // Carga un grupo de 10 audiovisuales
                for (int j = i; j < Math.min(i + 10, audiovisuales.size()); j++) {
                    final int pasarJ = j;
                    char primerCharAudiovisual = audiovisuales.get(i).getNombre().charAt(0);
                    if (!Character.isDigit(primerCharAudiovisual) && !Character.isLetter(primerCharAudiovisual)) {
                        count++;
                        final int pasarCount = count;
                        Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(audiovisuales.get(j).getNombre());
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                        // Ejecuta configurarImagen en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (FX Application Thread)
                        Platform.runLater(() -> configurarImagen(hyperlink, imageView, pasarCount, audiovisuales.get(pasarJ).getFoto()));
                    }
                }

                // Espera un breve tiempo para evitar bloquear la interfaz de usuario
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Maneja la interrupción del hilo
                }
            }

            // Actualiza el contenido del ScrollPane en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
            Platform.runLater(() -> scpCrollPane.setContent(principal));
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    private void replicado(MouseEvent event) {
        Object componente = event.getSource();
        String buscado = "";

        switch (componente) {
            case Hyperlink hyperlink -> {
                buscado = hyperlink.getText();
                hyperlink.setVisited(false);
            }
            case ImageView imageView ->
                buscado = imageView.getId();
            default -> {
            }
        }

        Audiovisual a = busquedaBinaria(buscado);

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader;
            Parent root;
            Stage myStage = (Stage) this.btnMenu.getScene().getWindow();
            if (a instanceof Juego juego) {
                loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista_interno_2/PlantillaJuegosVista.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();
                PlantillaJuegosVistaController controlador = loader.getController();
                controlador.inicializar(juego);
                f.superCompletar(myStage, root, controlador);
            } else if (a instanceof Película || a instanceof Animado) {
                loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista_interno_2/PlantillaPelisVista.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();
                PlantillaPelisVistaController controlador = loader.getController();
                controlador.inicializar((Película) a);
                f.superCompletar(myStage, root, controlador);
            } else {
                loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista_interno_2/PlantillaSeriesVista.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();
                PlantillaSeriesVistaController controlador = loader.getController();
                controlador.inicializar(a);
                f.superCompletar(myStage, root, controlador);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            error(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    private Audiovisual busquedaBinaria(String buscado) {
        Audiovisual a = null;
        int inicio = 0;
        int fin = audiovisuales.size() - 1;
        boolean romper = false;

        while (inicio <= fin && !romper) {
            int medio = inicio + (fin - inicio) / 2;
            String nombreMedio = audiovisuales.get(medio).getNombre();

            if (buscado.equalsIgnoreCase(nombreMedio)) {
                a = audiovisuales.get(medio);
                romper = true; // Encontramos el elemento, salimos del bucle
            } else if (buscado.compareToIgnoreCase(nombreMedio) < 0) {
                fin = medio - 1; // El elemento buscado está en la mitad izquierda
            } else {
                inicio = medio + 1; // El elemento buscado está en la mitad derecha
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * **********************************************************************************************************************
     */
    private void configurarImagen(Hyperlink hyperlink, ImageView imageView, int count, String foto) {
        File file = new File(foto);
        Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageView.setImage(img);
        imageView.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView.setFitHeight(280);
        imageView.setId(hyperlink.getText());
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(this::replicado);

        hyperlink.setWrapText(true);
        hyperlink.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        hyperlink.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hyperlink.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        hyperlink.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white; "
                + "-fx-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; "
                + "-fx-font-size: 18; " + "-fx-font-weight: bold;"
                + "-fx-focus-traversable: false;");
        hyperlink.setPrefWidth(200);
        hyperlink.setOnMouseClicked(this::replicado);

        // Agregar los elementos al GridPane
        hyperlinks.add(hyperlink);
        GridPane.setHalignment(imageView, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setHalignment(hyperlink, HPos.CENTER);
        principal.add(imageView, count % 4, 2 * (count / 4));
        principal.add(hyperlink, count % 4, 2 * (count / 4) + 1);
    }


    @FXML
    private void scrollMoviendose(ScrollEvent event) {
        if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) { // Desplazarse hacia abajo
            //Poner condicion de que si el scroll esta en el inicio no se haga nada
            //volver nulos lo imageView de arriba y cargar los de abajo
        } else {// Desplazarse hacia arriba
            //Poner condicion de que si el scroll esta en el final no se haga nada
            //cargar los de arriba y volver nulos lo imageView de abajo
        }
    }
  

}


Viste esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951470/14083367 Javafx tiene clases que funcionan similar a un recyclerview de android, que reutiliza las vistas y solo cargas las cosas que están realmente en pantalla. Porque imagino que cuando creas la lista de miles de imágenes no estarás cargándolas ya en memoria, no? Una lista de 5k de strings OK... una lista de 5k de imágenes pesadas, uff. Yo solo las cargaría cuando realmente las necesitas, y reutilizando los objetos donde las almacenas para evitar crear más y más objetos constantemente.

Una forma es hacer una carga por paginacion si la misma esta siendo hecho desde la base de datos.
Otra manera es que si tienes las imagenes en disco o las rutas de las mismas podrias colocar un Listener que escuche el desplazamiento del Scrollbar y que te actualice las imagenes a medida que va mostrando....entonces que muestre la que estas viendo algunas de las posteriores y otras las anteriories....ejemplo.
5 imagenes anteriores
5 imagenes actual que estas viendo
5 imagenes posteriores
para que cuando avances la lista o retrocedas des tiempo a la carga a todas las imagenes que estan mas alla de las 5 posteriores o anteriores. Pero siempre tendras en memoria 15 imagenes....si la lista es mas larga ya dependera de ti.
